# Could not locate cfg.xml resource with hibernate.5.2.2.Final + spring.4.0.6.RELEASE in IDEA 2018.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, hibernate.cfg.xml

I upgraded my Idea from `2017.1` to `2018.1` and I have a Hibernate issue I can't solve... I've searched and it seems there are many problems with this but couldn't figure out what's the solution.

So, I'm using hibernate.version `5.2.2.Final`, spring.version `4.0.6.RELEASE`, my `hibernate.cfg.xml` is in `src\main\resources` folder and in my HibernateUtils I had something like this:

```
public class HibernateUtils {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the ServiceRegistry from hibernate.cfg.xml
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

            // Create a metadata sources using the specified service registry.
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();

            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
```

}

And this was working until I upgraded my IDEA. Now I have some

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mgo.HibernateUtils.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.java:34)
    at org.mgo.HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.java:11)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

I tried everything I found with this error, to put the `hibernate.cfg.xml` directly into src folder, to point the path to the xml file like `"/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml"` or `"/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml"`, or to leave it empty like this `.configure()` but nothing seems to work.

I found in here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21340
something that it doesn't works with `Spring 4.3.17.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.2.17.Final` and works with `Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.1.14.Final` but if I change like this I get many other errors and I don't get it why my hibernate.5.2.2.Final + spring.4.0.6.RELEASE doesn't works anymore because of my IDEA. As I am using Maven, I tried to compile outside of Idea but facing the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

huh, maybe this will help somebody... I did it without an hibernate.cfg.xml, like this: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-5-java-configuration-example

```
public class HibernateUtils {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        if (null == sessionFactory) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
                Properties settings = new Properties();

                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DBA;instance=SQLEXPRESS");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "user");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "xxx");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
                settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

                configuration.setProperties(settings);

                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass1.class);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass2.class);

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```